# List Of Dictionary to List of List<string> in LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

HI I have this example data which is in List<Dictionary<string,string>>

```
var menu = new List<Dictionary<string,string>> { new Dictionary<string, string> { { "Meal", "Pasta" }, { "Meal", "Pizza" } } , new Dictionary<string, string> { { "Entree", "Calamari Salad" } } },
```

I need to convert the above list to something like this

```
var menu = new List<List<string>> { new List<string> { "Meal:Pasta", "Meal:Pizza" }, new List<string> { "Entree:Calamari Salad" } };
```

how can I do this with LINQ query?

Comment: Would be great if you can share the attempt. Thanks.

Comment: the first one will make error as there are two "Meal" keys in the dictionary `{ "Meal", "Pasta" }, { "Meal", "Pizza" }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try like below.

```
var result = menu.Select(x => x.Select(y => $"{y.Key}:{y.Value}"));
```

Answer (score 3):

First of all you will receive an exception, that `"Meal"` key already exist in dictionary.

Secondly, if you need to have the same types as you mentioned:

`List<List<string>> result = menu.Select(m => m.Select(x => $"{x.Key}:{x.Value}").ToList()).ToList();`

So result will looks like:

[image]

Please note, that I have replaced key and value for dictionary `"Meal"` to avoid receiving exeption about existing key.

Comment: better answer due to the error having two keys